# Did the Christian Democratic Union of Germany (CDU) post this advert in Turkish?

Tags: politics, germany

On 14 September 2017, [Hamed Abdel-Samad](https://www.facebook.com/hamed.abdelsamad/posts/10155684625165979:0) and [Erika Steinbach](https://www.facebook.com/erika.steinbach/posts/1379562348829705) posted on Facebook, referencing the following image, which is purportedly a [CDU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_Democratic_Union_of_Germany) advert:

[image]

The three main points roughly translate (according to Google Translate) as:

> 1. For better jobs and salaries. We will invest in crafts and vocational training to strengthen tradesmen and middle class.
> 2. The best education for all children - regardless of the origin and identity of anyone. We want to prepare our schools in the digital age and we want to create better opportunities for qualified staff.
> 3. More respect for the family. We will raise the monthly child's allowance of 25 euros per child for the families with children and we will raise the child tax exemption.

The third point is about child support ("Kindergeld" in German). This is [a known CDU electoral promise](https://www.welt.de/politik/deutschland/article166193255/Union-plant-nach-der-Wahl-Erhoehung-des-Kindergeldes.html) (German source.)

Does the above image depict a real advert run by the CDU? If so, where did the ad run?

Comment: The reason for asking is that it started getting attention on right-wing blogs and Facebook, with only the photo in the OP offered as proof. The most conservative party in the current Bundestag targeting turkish voters with only three pillars, one of which is raising child allowance, seems to legitimate the AfD (more right-wing than Merkel's CDU.) My intention was to clarify whether these were _fake_ news.

Comment: Even though it seems to be genuine, it's a legitimate question, given how plausible it would be for this to be made up.

Comment: @knallfrosch Is the issue specifically that they're targeting people who speak Turkish, or the fact that they're only advertising those three points to those people (leaving out positions that may possibly negatively affect the Turkish population in Germany)?

Answer (score 18):

**Yes**.

The German far-right website [PI News](http://www.pi-news.net/cdu-wirbt-auf-tuerkisch-fuer-den-geburtendschihad/) claims that this ad was in the free regional newspaper Werbezeitung Öztürk in Bielefeld on the 1st of September.

[An online edition](http://ozturk.de/sayi-319-eyluel-2017-bielefeld/) of the newspaper shows the ad on page 5.

Raising the Kindergeld by 25 Euros is [indeed](https://www.derwesten.de/politik/union-verspricht-mehr-geld-mehr-wohnungen-mehr-polizei-id211107935.html) a CDU election promise, being advertised to everyone, not just the Turkish-speaking community.)

Advertising with common election promises in a Turkish newspaper in Turkish doesn't seem unreasonable, nor unusual. There is a relatively large Turkish community in Germany, so targeting them makes sense. The SPD for example already used Turkish ads in [2011](http://www.berliner-kurier.de/berlin/kiez---stadt/-stolz-auf-neukoelln---berlin-wahlkampf-auf-tuerkisch-15094998) in Berlin. PI News [reported](http://www.pi-news.net/afd-wahlwerbung-in-turkischer-sprache/) in 2013 that even a far-right party advertised in Turkish (although the ads were later retracted).

Comment: Not only "not unusual" but standard practice. In every country I am aware of  all political parties distribute election materials  in minority languages (probably except ultranationalist parties).